Styles and css are not loaded in browser
i've updated my packages versions on react project, and styles now not loading.
in code i use styles like this:
    import styles from "../WrappersCommon.scss";
    ...
    <div className={styles["main-layout"]}>

in webpack config i have
       test: /.(scss)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: {
            localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            plugins: [postcssPresetEnv()],
          },
        },
      },
      "sass-loader",
    ],

There is no errors in terminal, and i don't see any styles in app, they are not even loaded in browser:



please help, what is wrong with styles?

You can try using the styles like this
<div className={styles.main_layout}>

instead of
<div className={styles["main-layout"]}>

Notice that I also replaced the "-" with "_" in the classname. Change that in your scss file too, and check again. I hope it will solve the problem, if not I can look for another solution.

thanks, but still doesn't work. Actually my code worked fine - i only updated packages versions when all went down. Updating to react 19 was a bad idea )
